# update and data: elems in shipping-address/list.html

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I've created a module to customise some of the functionality of the checkout in Magento 2.

In the template I'm using to override `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/list.html` I would like to create and access a new element called `addressSummary` which just needs to be a concatenation of `address().firstname` & `address().company`.

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
    <li data-bind="click: selectAddress, visible: !isQuoteAddressLocked" class="action item">
        <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko text: address().addressSummary --><!-- /ko -->
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I can add them easily with `<!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko -->`  but I need to have them in a single property so I can hopefully filter them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to add it to a function which called itself, in my module's 'web\js\view\shipping-address\list.js'

```
define([
   'ko',
   'mageUtils',
   'uiLayout',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list',
   'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list'
], function (ko, utils, layout, ListView, addressList) {
   'use strict';

   return ListView.extend({
       defaults: {
           template: 'Holy_Addresses/shipping-address/list'
       },

       updateElems: function () {

           _.each(addressList._latestValue, function(address) {
               address.addressSummary = address.company + ' ' + address.lastname;
           });

           return this;
       }.call(this),
```

Works pretty nicely.  I just needed to make sure `addressList` was listed the define function.

`Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list.js` is called after my file.  With...

```
[CODE OMMITED....]
addressList.subscribe(function (changes) {
        var self = this;

        changes.forEach(function (change) {
            if (change.status === 'added') {
                self.createRendererComponent(change.value, change.index);
            }
        });
    },
    this,
    'arrayChange'
);

[CODE OMMITED....]
utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
   address: ko.observable(address)
});
[CODE OMMITED....]
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect use case for a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

**Example using first and last name**

```
this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks, How could I use this in the template or from the `Magento-Checkout\web\js\view\shipping-address\list.js` which I'm overriding?

Comment: I don't have enough time to look into that sorry, having a quick glance I don't know if that's the best file to do this in as it doesn't seem to contain the customers firstname

Comment: `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js` may be a better bet as it contains the user's name and address.